# Insert key in mac book pro 2011 with windows 10 with bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, ms-office

I have a MacBook Pro 2011 running windows 10 with bootcamp.

How to use "Insert key" (Ins) or equivalent on Mac keyboard, in MS word 2016 ?

There isnt key insert, and fn + return doesn not work, and also bringing the windows onboard keybord does not send inset command ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For me to get insert to work on iMac with Linux and a Mac keyboard I had to use <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982946
Then fn+return works.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with any of the solutions. 
What i did was going on the On-Screen Keyboard (just search for it the windows search box) and click on the insert.